# ¿Cómo ocultar la ActionBar en Android?

Tags: java, android

Intento ocultar la barra con el nombre de la App o ActionBar, pero no lo he podido conseguir.

Captura:

[image]

Mi AndroidManifest es este:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

En Java tengo esto:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //to remove "information bar" above the action bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //to remove the action bar (title bar)
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

   // ...
}
```

Como guía he seguido [ésta](https://man.thelostweb.com/en/man/removehide-statustitle-bar-from-the-top-of-the-app.html), pero sin mucho éxito.

Por cierto, he completado styles.xml como sugiere el amigo @diegoveloper -gracias- pero no nuevamente sin resultados:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- added -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: Dejo un repositorio para que puedan ver el problema y de paso cuando termine el proyecto, servirà a alguien que estè aprendiendo como yo ahora.   https://github.com/boctulus/DarkCalc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Todos las respuestas hasta ahora son correctas pero la soluciòn venìa por remover una parte de activity_main.xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

¿Existe el estilo *AppTheme.NoActionBar*?

A mi me funciona bien utilizando el estilo *Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar*:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: Estimado: lo he probado pero no me funciona. Adicional uso un tema oscuro. Gracias

Comment: No importa si llamas al tema claro u oscuro para hacer el NoActionBar, ya que el resultado es que no se muestre.

Comment: En teoría no necesitas ni una línea de código en XML, la mera llamada a ese estilo oculta la barra. Es decir, no necesitas hacer un hide().

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre en este momento, es que en algún punto del código estás creando una toolbar personalizada y sin configuración.

Si esto es así, puedes probar una cosa: En vez de poner el estilo NoActionBar, pon un estilo visible. Pueden ocurrir dos cosas: Que salte un error, en cuyo caso significa que en algún lado estás intentando crear una toolbar personalizada habiendo ya una definida. O que salgan dos toolbars, en cuyo caso significaría que en algún XML estás creando ese elemento azul. Por probar...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar agregando esto:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: Amigo tu sugerencia alcanza a ocultar el "title bar" (actionBar) pero me sigue dejando otra barra (azul como en la captura) debajo.

Comment: Ya modifique mi respuesta-

Comment: Gracias amigo pero eso mismo si revisas ya estaba en el post.

Answer (score 0):

Crea tu estilo personalizado con lo siguiente:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>  
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Y usalo en tu `Activity` del manifest

El archivo que tienes que editar el styles.xml que está en la carpeta por default de values no en values-v21 etc. Verifica eso

Comment: Diego: desde ya gracias por tu tiempo. Hice algo así ahora incluso màs completo pero sigue sin funcionar. He actualizado el còdigo en el post.

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta, verificaste eso? Puedes indicar en que archivo lo tienes

Comment: Diego gracias, si de pura casualidad creo pero el archivo styles.xml que he editado es el que està en res/values.  Ya realmente no se que hacer....

Comment: Que version de android estas usando

Comment: La API target es 26 y la mínima 24. Gracias desde ya.

Comment: La version de tu dispositivo android o simulador

Answer (score 0):

Intenta asignarle el `theme` en el `Manifest.xml` en la definicion de la actividad:

```
<activity class=".MainActivity" 
   theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
/>
```

Comment: Gracias @Einer, alguien me dijo que removiera una parte de activity_main.xml  y entonces finalmente pude ocultar las barras de aplicación y notificación.  Todas las respuestas son correctas pero no funcionaba sin tocar ahí.